# Trying to set variable in the UI-Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I use this code to read from a weighting scale, I successfully read weight value from it but when trying to set the variable `hex = ""` for the next weight value I can't get it in the textbox, it appears very quickly and then disappears again, if I trace the program with the hex = "" enabled the results are as expected, but if run the program without trace it, then the blinking with the values and the textbox gets empty :( any ideas

```
        string hex = "";
        private delegate void Closure();
        private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)     
            {                
                BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     
            }
            else
            {
                if (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    //hex = "";  <- Without this different weight values appears one after another. If applied then happens what explained above.
                    while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) //<-- repeats until the In-Buffer is empty
                    {                        
                        hex += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());                        
                    }

                    byte[] data = FromHex(hex.Trim());
                    textBox1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).Trim();
                }
            }
        }

        public byte[] FromHex(string aHex)
        {
            aHex = aHex.Replace(" ", "");
            byte[] raw = new byte[aHex.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
            {
                raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(aHex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
            }
            return raw;
        }
```

This is the code to start listening:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //<-- This block ensures that no exceptions happen
            if (_serialPort != null && _serialPort.IsOpen)
                _serialPort.Close();
            if (_serialPort != null)
                _serialPort.Dispose();
            //<-- End of Block


            /*--- OHAUS Ranger Count Config ---*/
            //http://us.ohaus.com/us/en/home/support/faq.aspx
            _serialPort = new SerialPort(comboBox1.Text);
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 2400;
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 7;
            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.Two;
            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            /*--- End OHAUS Ranger Count Config ---*/

            label1.Text = "Listening on " + _serialPort.PortName + "...";

            _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortOnDataReceived;       //<- Here I add the event
            _serialPort.Open();     //<-- make the comport listen

        }
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to happen? It makes sense that when you don't have hex="" that it just shows the different weight values flashing; it's showing a new value every time serial data is received. When you add that line it's going to (just as quickly) clear out the received data each time more data is received. If you only want to receive the weight value once you can remove the event handler after the event is fired once.

Comment: I just want to have just a single weight value every time I press the `print` key in the weighting scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me, I added some delay before `hex = ""`, however I believe this is not a good practice though:

```
        string hex = "";
        private delegate void Closure();        
        private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)     
            {                
                BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));                
            }
            else
            {
                if (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
                {                    
                    Thread.Sleep(200);  //<-- Add some delay
                    hex = "";

                    while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) //<-- repeats until the In-Buffer is empty
                    {                        
                        hex += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());                        
                    }

                    byte[] data = FromHex(hex.Trim());                    
                    textBox1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).Trim();                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it an option for you to just let the numbers change until they stop coming in? Sort of like an actual scale does when you step on it and it's calculating. It seems like if the scale stops sending you values after a Thread.Sleep(200) you may not be ending up with the most accurate result. What if the "best" result is the last one sent? Just something to think about.

Comment: The thing is that I press the 'Print' button when I ready to get the weight value, and by that moment, the scale is stable with the right weight.

Comment: Gotcha. Only other thing I can think of is if you would add an if statement that checks if textBox1.Text is "" and if it is, add the value; if it's not, do nothing. Then just set it back to "" on the button click event.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the method that is called when you press the print key, you can add the serial port event handler:

```
_serialPort.OnDataReceived+=SerialPortOnDataReceived;
```

Then, at the end of your `SerialPortOnDataReceived` method (after the successful read), remove the event handler from the serial port object. This will make it stop listening for new data on the serial port until you press print again.

```
private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)     
    {                
        BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     
    }
    else
    {
        if (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            //hex = "";  <- Without this different weight values appears one after another. If applied then happens what explained above.
            while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) //<-- repeats until the In-Buffer is empty
            {                        
                hex += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());                        
            }

            byte[] data = FromHex(hex.Trim());
            textBox1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).Trim();
            _serialPort.OnDataReceived-=SerialPortOnDataReceived; // <---add this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please review my edited code above, I did what you told me to do, and keep doing the same. Appears one measure next to the other.

Comment: Did you also add the line to the `SerialPortOnDataReceived` method?

Comment: I just added first the `_serialPort.DataReceived-=SerialPortOnDataReceived;` where you told me, the results there was just zeros in the textbox when press `PRINT`, then I added the `_serialPort.DataReceived+=SerialPortOnDataReceived;` at the beginning of the method and one measure next to other starts to show in the textbox

Comment: Can you post your current code for both the button click and the event handler method?

Comment: They are already posted. The first one is the event handler method, and the second one is the button click.

Comment: You did not add the line to remove the event handler at the end of SerialPortOnDataReceived

Comment: I did, but as seen not the expected results I deleted again. Anyways if I trace the program with the `hex = ""` enabled the results are as expected, but if run the program without trace it, then the blinking with the values and the textbox gets empty :( any ideas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62193/discussion-between-eddie-cat-and-somebody).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I update the UI thread.

```
    delegate void SerialPortOnDataReceivedDelegate(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs);
    private void SerialPortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            BeginInvoke(new SerialPortOnDataReceivedDelegate(SerialPortOnDataReceived), new object[] { sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs });
        else
        {
            if (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                //hex = "";  <- Without this different weight values appears one after another. If applied then happens what explained above.
                while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) //<-- repeats until the In-Buffer is empty
                {                        
                    hex += string.Format("{0:X2} ", _serialPort.ReadByte());                        
                }

                byte[] data = FromHex(hex.Trim());
                textBox1.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data).Trim();
            }
        }
    }
    public byte[] FromHex(string aHex)
    {
        aHex = aHex.Replace(" ", "");
        byte[] raw = new byte[aHex.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
        {
            raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(aHex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }
        return raw;
    }
```

Comment: Dmitri, same results with your approach, see image above.